# Running OpenGL application without any graphic server

Tags: opengl, graphics, rendering, headless, off-screen

I want to write application for digital signage but I want it to run in minimal environment so I don't want X11 server. Is it possible to run on one account OpenGl app without X11 (or any other graphic drawing library with at least 2D graphics)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I`m working in a very similar project.  Since for me the need to run opengl without xserver was primarily performance based, I opeted instead to install damn small linux to a flash drive along with the program i wrote.  Damn small linux is super small (50 mb for the entire os), and since its designed to run on low spec hardware (it can be run on a pentium 1 with 16 mb of ram) it uses a minimal ammount of system resources.  I just run ny application on top of damn small linux, and it performs extremely well.

Answer (score 4):

One way is via the [Mesa off-screen rendering API](http://www.mesa3d.org/osmesa.html).  Be aware that this will most likely be unaccelerated.

If you just don't want X11 and you're willing to use [OpenGL ES](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/OpenGL_ES) then [Wayland](http://wayland.freedesktop.org/faq.html) and corresponding [Gallium](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gallium3D) drivers would get you hardware acceleration.

Comment: Wayland is not nearly complete, and also the Wayland compositor will most likely require a physical screen. Technically Gallium could be extended to allow for GPU accelerated offscreen rendering, but so far this is not implemented.